# How to import aws elb cert from one account to another?

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-iam, amazon-elb

I have two different accounts of aws so the cert present on elb in one account,i want the same cert for different account because we have same dns. 
How can i import same cert to different account as well. 
When i try to get that cert and upload that cert with cert chain ,cert and private key it says certificate not in pem format. So that means get-server-cert api doesn't return pem format,it it?
Any help would be really appreciated. 
Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export a server certificate from IAM, not enough information is returned to allow you to use the certificate elsewhere.

This is by design.  It is a security feature.

You need to find the original private key.  While you're at it, you can just use the original cert and chain files.

> `$ aws iam get-server-certificate --server-certificate-name ExampleCertificate`
>
> When the preceding command is successful, it returns the certificate, the certificate chain (if one was uploaded), and metadata about the certificate.
>
> **Note**
>
> You cannot download or retrieve a private key from IAM after you upload it.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html#get-server-certificate

Assuming you are already ahead of me, here, and that you do have the original private key, you should be able to use the results from `aws get-server-certificate` for the cetificate and chain, because they should already be in PEM format, which looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...multiple lines of base64...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The certificate has exactly one such block, and the chain has one or more such blocks.

Your private key, in PEM format, looks similar, but has words other than `CERTIFICATE` in the boundary markers, such as `RSA PRIVATE KEY`.

Be sure the number of dashes on the left and right of each boundary marker is exactly 5.

Comment: Thanks , It helped !